# How to get x first objects from table - lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm pretty new in lua and I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for several hours now.
So simply I have one table with 4 other tables (sry idk how it's named).

```
local myTable = {
 player1 = {id = 1, points = 100},
 player2 = {id = 3, points = 200},
 player3 = {id = 4, points = 150},
 player4 = {id = 7, points = 150}}
```

*Id and points are random numbers*.
All I want to do is get only 2 first tables from that table and use their values.

```
player1 = {id = 1, points = 100}
player2 = {id = 3, points = 200}
```

I would really appreciate your help, it's very tiring.

Answer (score 0):

> All I want to do is get only 2 first tables from that table and use
> their values.

To get the inner tables just index `myTable` with the keys you've stored to inner tables at.

```
local table1 = myTable.player1
local table2 = myTable.player2

print("Player 1 has " .. table1.points .. " points")
```

> How to get x first objects from table - lua

To answer this you would need to have a table with an order. Lua doesn't know the order of your table unless you have numerical keys.

If your table was like

```
local players = {
 {id = 1, points = 100},
 {id = 3, points = 200},
 {id = 4, points = 150},
 {id = 7, points = 150}}
```

You would simply pick `players[1]` and so forth to get the first x elements.

In your case you could do something like

`myTable["player"..i]` for `i` from 1 to x assuming that the keys represent the table order.

Answer (score 0):

First you need is sort your table:

```lua
local myTable = {
    {id = 1, points = 100},
    {id = 3, points = 200},
    {id = 4, points = 150},
    {id = 7, points = 150}
}
```

You don't need to index those values as 'player1', 'player2', etc. So if you want the index(es) to appear as player1, etc. return the index and concatenated as player, like:

```lua
for key, value in pairs(myTable) do
    print('player' .. key)
end
```

The past code will print all table indexes with prefix 'player'.
But to get only the first two values; what we can do? Simple! Make a function:

```lua
local myTable = {
    {id = 1, points = 100},
    {id = 3, points = 200},
    {id = 4, points = 150},
    {id = 7, points = 150}
}

local function collect(table, howMuch)
    local response, index = {}, 1
    for key, value in pairs(table) do
        response[key] = howMuch and index <= howMuch and value or nil
        index = index + 1
    end
    return response
end

local response = collect(myTable, 2)
print(response[1].id, response[2].id, response[3]) -- 1, 3, nil
```

What this function do?
Collect values from the first argument named `table`, and in base the second argument named `howMuch` (as a max of the response) return those values.

Or for friends: iters table `myTable` and only returning a table containing 2 fields.

Comment: tyvm for replying, rly helpful :]